# how to get the following css to work in tablet portrait

Tags: css

I am trying to get my css to work in a tablet portrait and when testing it on my tablet, I can't get any of my changes to work. Am I suppose to do a hard reset on the tablet or something?

```
    /*Tablet portrait with a width of 1024px*/

    @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait){
    label {
      width: 100%;
      display: block;
      position: relative;


    }

    .nav {
      width: 200%;

    }

    #nav-icon {
      font-size: 28px;
      line-height: 50px;
      padding-left: 1em;
      color:  #ffffff;
      background-color: #f44336;
    }

}
```

Comment: There's a closing curly brace `}` missing from the code that closes the @media screen section

Comment: I know because that is only part of the code but are we meant to do a hard reset or something?

Comment: Realised there's more code_ just thought that maybe the section wasn't closed_ which might have explained why it wasn't working _ I don't know anything about 'hard reset' on a tablet so can't answer the question (No harm in trying reset I guess)

Comment: I added the `}` for clarity ; )

Comment: I rebooted my tablet but still nothing is happening

Comment: here's another SO question that might help >>> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37748941/media-query-for-phone-works-but-not-tablet

Comment: This is strange because it is working in my chrome extension but not under my actual tablet

Comment: Cache clear. Mobile or desktop, browsers do not automatically reload style sheets. You must disable cache or clear it manually. Check the browser settings there.

Comment: I had clear the cache but it still doesn't work.. I guess I should disable cache then?